ТГ бот не обновляет кнопки в меню
Сделал реферального бота (с помощью нейросетей) создал все кнопки, все работало хорошо, но когда решил добавить новые кнопки в меню, в старых юзеров они просто напросто не отображаются, в новых пользователей все отлично, в чем может быть проблема? Если нужно сперва на код глянуть, могу скинуть.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
